# How to check if md5 is empty?

Tags: php, hash, md5

I am using md5 hash to store password into the database. I know empty string also have md5 hash.

#### My question is how I can check if user give me a empty string?

**I mean:**
user can give `""` and it can also give me a space `"  "` how will I differentiate between them. Yes I can use `trim` for normal php code and then check if it is empty or not. but how can I check if it is md5?

Comment: You should not hash passwords with md5 anymore. It's considered insecure nowadays. If you are on a recent version of PHP, use http://php.net/password. Also see http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/04/introducing-passwordlib.html for a more detailed explanation and backwards compatible alternatives.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do here: if your passwords were properly secured (and they're not if you're using md5), then *nobody* should be able to find out what they are just by looking at the hash. If you want to prevent users setting a blank password, you should check that when they enter it, *before* you create the hashed version.

Comment: @Gordon so I should stop using md5 and start using blowfish.

Comment: @hamza there's blowfish and other encryption types that are of better availability and security

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check if your string is empty first before you encrypt it?

anyway this piece of code will do the trick

```
<?php
$md5 = 'd67c5cbf5b01c9f91932e3b8def5e5f8';
$flag = Check_Valid_Md5_String($md5);
if ($flag){ // flag true means string is a valid md5 encrypation
echo 'valid md5 string';
}else{
echo 'invalid md5 string or empty string';
}

//this function will check the string
function Check_Valid_Md5_String($md5=''){
if(empty($md5)) return false;
return preg_match('/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/', $md5);
}
?>
```

[Reference](http://phptechnologytutorials.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/check-valid-md5-string-in-php/)

Comment: Apart from being all kinds of ugly, I'm pretty sure this code isn't what the question is asking for: they specifically mention the *user* entering an empty string, which will still lead to a valid md5 hash.